# I call a function in a loop and store the results in a matrix, how can I parallelize it?

Tags: python, mpi4py

I am new to python, I have a code in which I call a special function g times, and restore the result of that function as two columns of a final matrix, so at the end of this "for loop" I have a matrix with 10 columns, storing the result of 5 calls,

would you please guide me how can do this 5 calls, with 5 cores instead?

part of code which I want to parallelize is:

```
for r in range(5):
    Final[:,2*r:2*r+2]=my_function(X)
```

I did:

```
Final[:,2*rank:2*rank+2]=my_function(X)
```

but after doing `mpiexec -np 4 python comm.py` I understood that it was not enough, there must be some other things like `Barrier(`) or `send()` `recive()` I don't know,... would you please guide me?